# mongodb error : query has to be blank or an Object

Tags: php, mongodb

When I run this query

```
$count = smongo::$db->sessions->find(array(),array('cd'=>1))->count();
```

I get the following error:

```
Array ( [assertion] => query has to be blank or an Object [assertionCode] => 13608 [errmsg] => db assertion failure [ok] => 0 )
```

mongodb version 2.0.6
on the php.

How can I solve it.

Comment: What driver version and PHP version is this?

Comment: Apache/2.2.18 (Unix) PHP/5.3.6

Comment: And the Mongo PHP Extension version?

Comment: What if you put `null` there instead, though that is weird you should be able to enter a empty array into there. Does this happen on `1.2.10` for you since I know your code works there.

Comment: Into the first param of find() I meant.

Comment: Also does `find()` go directly to the Mongo driver or does it go to an abstraction layer?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting can only be generated by the mapReduce() code in MongoDB.  The most likely cause of this problem is that you're getting an exception from another command, and not the find() command that you have listed above.

I was not able to reproduce this problem using your code.  I suspect that if you try to create a test case yourself, you will find that **YOU** can't reproduce this using your sample code.  Look carefully for a mapReduce() command that is being run in the same exception-catching context as the code sample you posted.

Comment: I Cleaned before and after this command. This page only gives the command, although it is still an error. As you said, the error associated with MapReduce. But I could not find a solution.

Comment: There is nothing MapReduce functions. That is not complicated. Even on another computer running the same functions.

Comment: Did not find a solution to the problem, Problem is in another place.